# Why is passing an array as an argument causing each item in the array to be repeated?

Tags: javascript, arrays, arguments

I'm doing a function which returns an array. Then running another function which takes the aforementioned array as it's argument.

When I console.log() the array which is being returned from the original funtion, it shows each item once - as expected. BUT when I pass that as an argument into the second function, and then immediately console.log() the argument, it shows the array but with each item repeated! ‍♂️‍♂️‍♂️

Can anyone shed any light on that? Thanks!

---

Also, as a slightly separate question: I'm a complete beginner (as you can see) and I'm wondering whether this is even the correct way to 'chain' consecutive functions. I need one to run, and then to use the output of that first function as the argument for the next function. If anyone knows a slicker way, I'm all ears.
Thanks for your help!

````
const isColourful = num => {
    const arr = num.toString().split('');
    const arrayOfArrays = [];


    const arrayMaker = arr => {
        for (let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
            for (let i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
                i > j && arrayOfArrays.push(Number(arr.slice(j, i).reduce((a, cV) => a * cV)));
            }
        }
        return arrayOfArrays.sort((a, b) => a - b);
    };
    console.log('arrayMaker(arr):', arrayMaker(arr));
    // displays in console --> arrayMaker(arr): [ 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 20, 35, 40, 140, 280 ]



    const checker = a => {
        const counts = [];
        console.log('a: ', a);
        // displays in console --> a:  [ 2, 2, 4, 4, 5, 5, 7, 7, 8, 8, 20, 20, 35, 35, 40, 40, 140, 140, 280, 280 ]

        for (let k = 0; k < a.length; k++) {
            if (counts[a[k]] === undefined) {
                // counts[a[k]] = 1;
                // console.log(counts[a[k]]);
                // return 'This is NOT a colorful number!';
            }
            // return 'This IS a colorful number!';
        }
    };

    checker(arrayMaker(arr));
    // is this the 'proper' way to call the 2nd function, telling is to take the output of the first function as it's argument?
};

isColourful(2457);```
````

Comment: You are calling `arrayMaker` twice (once for your first console log, once at the end of `isColorful`), and it mutates and returns a variable `arrayOfArrays`, which is not local to the function. Therefore, your first call being different to your second isn't surprising.

Comment: That's great, ASDFGerte. Thanks so much!